# Given a tail transaction hash, can it returns multiple bundles by calling `get_bundles`?

Tags: iri-legacy-api, pyota

According to [pyota](https://github.com/iotaledger/iota.lib.py/blob/master/iota/api.py#L530) library, it states that `get_bundles()` may return multiple bundles with a specific transaction hash. But even we replay/reattach the bundle, its transactions' hash will change. I wonder in which circumstance it is possible to return list of matching bundles with one transaction only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the original [API Proposal](https://github.com/iotaledger/wiki/blob/master/api-proposal.md#getbundle), it mentions that `getBundle()` may return multiple bundles:

> If there are multiple bundles (because of a replay for example), it will return multiple bundles.

When I implemneted PyOTA, I used the API Proposal to design the interface, and I based the implementation off of the iota.lib.js library.

At the time, the JS `getBundle()` method always returned a single bundle regardless of circumstances, so I didn't know how to make PyOTA's `get_bundles()` method return multiple bundles, but I still wanted to keep the interface flexible for when that functionality was finally implemented.

However, it appears that this functionality has been definitively dropped; the API Proposal hasn't been updated in nearly 2 years, and in the [most recent version of iota.js](https://github.com/iotaledger/iota.js/blob/v1.0.0-beta.5/packages/core/src/createGetBundle.ts#L46), the `getBundle()` method is still documented as always returning a single bundle.

It might be worthwhile to add something to the [PyOTA issue tracker](https://github.com/iotaledger/iota.lib.py/issues/) to reconcile this disparity with the JS lib.